# Why is android SimpleCursorAdapter bindView duplicating the first row?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have extended SimpleCursorAdapter and am running into a weird issue with bindView, which appears to be called twice on the first row.

Only the first row appears to be duplicated. I have a feeling it has something to do with the way the cursor is positioned, but have looked through all the adapter classes and can't seem to locate where this occurs.

Here is my code for bindView, I have inserted some Logs to show what I'm seeing.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewBinder binder = getViewBinder();
    final int count = mTo.length;
    final int[] from = mFrom;
    final int[] to = mTo;

    Log.v("builder", "cursor count"+cursor.getCount() );

    Log.v("builder", "mTo.length"+count);
    //Bind all Views
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
            boolean bound = false;
            if (binder != null) {
                bound = binder.setViewValue(v, cursor, from[i]);
            }

            if (!bound) {
                String text = cursor.getString(from[i]);
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (text == null && !(v instanceof ImageView)) {
                    text = "";
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } 

                if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                    if (v instanceof EditText){
                        EditText et = (EditText) v;
                        Log.v("builder", "setting up edittext"+cursor.getPosition()+i);
                    //  setUpEditors(view, et);
                    }
                } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                            " view that can be bound by this SimpleCursorAdapter");
                }


            }
        }
    }


}
```

Here is my output with only one item in the cursor

```
06-22 15:15:03.797: V/builder(27573): cursor count1
06-22 15:15:03.797: V/builder(27573): mTo.length5
06-22 15:15:03.807: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext02
06-22 15:15:03.807: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext03
06-22 15:15:03.807: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext04
06-22 15:15:03.887: V/builder(27573): cursor count1
06-22 15:15:03.887: V/builder(27573): mTo.length5
06-22 15:15:03.897: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext02
06-22 15:15:03.897: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext03
06-22 15:15:03.907: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext04
```

Here it is with 2 items

```
06-22 15:17:28.337: V/builder(27573): cursor count2
06-22 15:17:28.337: V/builder(27573): mTo.length5
06-22 15:17:28.337: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext02
06-22 15:17:28.337: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext03
06-22 15:17:28.337: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext04
06-22 15:17:28.417: V/builder(27573): cursor count2
06-22 15:17:28.417: V/builder(27573): mTo.length5
06-22 15:17:28.417: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext02
06-22 15:17:28.427: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext03
06-22 15:17:28.427: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext04
06-22 15:17:28.517: V/builder(27573): cursor count2
06-22 15:17:28.517: V/builder(27573): mTo.length5
06-22 15:17:28.527: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext12
06-22 15:17:28.527: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext13
06-22 15:17:28.527: V/builder(27573): setting up edittext14
```

Here's the xml where the ListView is located

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/labels_background"
    android:text="@string/lb_item_type"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dm_maint_tv" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/mt_base"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lb_base" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/labels_background"
    android:text="@string/lb_build"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dm_maint_tv" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/builder">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mt_build_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mt_additem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_input_add" android:layout_gravity="top|right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It means that I enjoyed the narrative. (i.e. there is no evidence of a question... nor do you ever imply that there is an issue).

Comment: and I QUOTE "am running into a weird issue with bindView, which appears to be called twice on the first row."

Comment: OK, then why didn't you set your title "why is bindview getting called twice?" or something... seriously, your post is just not very clear at all lol. At least use a question mark somewhere...

Comment: You havent overriden any of the other `SimpleCursorAdapter` methods, have you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the sequence `newView`/`bindView` called twice per item, you are probably using ListView with its height set to wrap_content, which is always a bad idea. Can you confirm that you are not doing this?

Also, I can't say for sure but this might be perfectly valid behavior, if your first list item is being called twice I mean. It sounds like Android must measure the first list item (which requires the system to call `bindView` one time) and *then* populate the list item (also by calling `bindView`. After the first row is populated (which requires two calls to `bindView`), the width of each subsequent list item is known and requires only one call to `bindView` per each item. Let me know if that makes sense...

Either way, I hope this isn't something you are worried about... one additional call to `bindView` won't kill your app. :)

Comment: Ok just for you, I have updated the title as well as adding the layout xml. The ListView is set to matchparent both ways. It also isn't duplicating all rows, just the first one.

Comment: That does make sense, but it also breaks my app.. Each ListView Item has 3 EditTexts and I was hoping to use a TextWatcher on any of the 3 to detect a change and allow the user to save the row. Because bindView is called twice on the first item, The textwatcher triggers and acts as if the data has always changed