# SimpleCursorAdapter bindView displays image randomly on the list

Tags: listview, view, simplecursoradapter

BindView marks random lines. I've tried to check the values of the data and the if statement works fine. All I want to do is the image to appear (set visible) when the completion letter in the database ='T'. So why is it marking random lines?

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, 
        R.layout.component_details, 
        null, 
        columns, 
        to, 
        0){                         
            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {                   
                super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
                View completed = findViewById(R.id.txt_completed);
                String completedColumn = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Db.COLUMN_COMPLETED));                  
                ImageView imgview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon_check);
                if(completedColumn.equals("T")){
                    imgview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Lockwood and his answer from the post  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162758/why-is-android-simplecursoradapter-bindview-duplicating-the-first-row?rq=1)  solved my problem. I think its ridiculous but things like wrap_content of the listView does matter! :)